# Error shows windows path for Tesseract on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have received the following error when running Spyder in Anaconda on a Mac:

```
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 345, in get_tesseract_version
    raise TesseractNotFoundError()

TesseractNotFoundError: C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe is not installed or it's not in your PATH
```

I ran

```
brew install imagemagick
brew install tesseract
```

in the mac terminal and then

```
pip install tesseract
```

and

```
pip install tesseract-ocr
```

in the spyder terminal. I have since restarted spyder and attempted to run my program. It worked previously on a different computer.

Aside from it not working, I am doubly confused as it appears to be trying to find a windows path for tesseract.

How do I get tesseract running in spyder?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my own question here:

The program I was running was ported over from a Windows computer.

In that program, I had to specify the path to tesseract, which was the windows directory listed in the question, so it was locked to the windows directory I specified.

The correct path can be found in the MacOS terminal by typing

```
brew list tesseract
```

where it is the first line. (Note that home-brew must be installed for this.)

Replacing the path in my code with the path from the terminal query fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue in Mac M1 with following steps:-

1. `brew install tesseract`
2. Check the directory of tesseract `brew list tesseract`
3. Provide path of tesseract in code: `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tesseract/5.2.0/bin/tesseract'`

Comment: Use code formatting